# How to type pinyin text with tone marks in Windows?

Tags: windows, chinese, ime

How do I type Chinese [**pinyin**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinyin) text with the tone marks into any application in Windows?

I am aware of the Chinese IME in Windows, which converts pinyin text I type into the Chinese stroked characters. This is **not** what I want. I want to type and view pinyin text, like **rì chū** for example, with all the proper tone marks ([diacritics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic)).

Comment: You can mark the tone at the end instead of the accent. wo3 = I, ta1 = he/she, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [U.S. international keyboard](http://tlt.its.psu.edu/suggestions/international/accents/codeint.html) that comes with Windows makes typing some accents easy, but apparently not macrons (the bar over the "u" in "chū").  The [Māori keyboard](http://kupu.maori.nz/Show.aspx?page=12) has support for those; maybe you can hot switch between the two?  Someone [claimed to have made](http://www.unilang.org/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=6001#p497794) a derivative of the international keyboard that permits typing the macrons as well as other accents easily, but I haven't tried it out.

You could try using a [tone converter](http://pinyin.info/unicode/marks3.html) that takes in numeric-based tones and spits out accent-based tones.

**Edit:**

I found an explicitly [pinyin keyboard layout](http://robrohan.com/2007/02/18/typing-pinyin-on-windows-part-a-better-way/) that should do what you want.

Comment: By the time you shared this keyboard layout, I took your earlier advice and created my own layout: http://qishi.wordpress.com/2009/08/23/pinyin-keyboard-layout/   :-)

Comment: Fortune favors the bold!  Nice job.

Comment: @AshwinNanjappa your wordpress has been deleted. Any new place to find your layout?

Comment: I found a new link for the pinyin keyboard layout here: https://robrohan.com/2007/02/18/typing-pinyin-on-windows-part-a-better-way/index.html

Comment: For users using the link from @davidtbernal make sure you enable "Compatability mode" for .msi installer otherwise it won't work on Windows 10+

URL: https://robrohan.com/2007/02/18/typing-pinyin-on-windows-part-a-better-way/index.html

Answer (score 7):

May I suggest my own PinyinTones IME, which does exactly what the OP was looking for:

- [https://www.pinyintones.com/](http://www.pinyintones.com/)

It's a Windows IME that outputs Pinyin with tone marks, rather than Chinese characters.  Type 1, 2, 3, or 4 after each syllable to add a tone mark -- just as people have been entering Pinyin since the days of ASCII characters:

[image: Pinyin IME to type Pinyin with tone marks into any Windows application]

Key features:

1. Uses the Text Services Framework, so it works everywhere that the Microsoft Pinyin IME works.  Including desktop and Universal applications.
2. Uses in-line text composition, just like the Microsoft IMEs.  This means that it behaves well in TSF-aware applications -- for example, when inserting, text will reflow as you type.
3. Automatically places tone marks on the correct vowel in a combination, according to the rules of Pinyin orthography.  (e.g., hao3 becomes hǎo -- with the tone mark on the "a" rather than on the "o")

Comment: What does this do when you press the TAB key? In notepad it seems to defer tabbing until you press enter. When you're in a combo box it seems to make it impossible to change focus using your keyboard. Is this a standard IME 'feature' and if so what is the purpose of it?

Comment: Also, it's constantly in "insert" mode, so you cannot move the cursor to the middle of a sentence, it will overwrite any following characters

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [Keyboard Layout Creator](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=FB7B3DCD-D4C1-4943-9C74-D8DF57EF19D7&displaylang=en) to create such a keyboard layout yourself. Off the top of my head I don't know a layout which enables you to type all the tones. As Bkkbrad mentioned, you can't type a macron on US International (which is what I'm using here). But modifying US International to add another dead key for macron shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 4):

I've used a couple but in the end I went with **[QuickPinyin](http://www.chinese-forums.com/index.php?/topic/37827-quickpinyin-type-pinyin-with-tone-marks-portable/)** because it's the only one that didn't need to be installed. This is kind of cool because I can run from a USB stick on any PC, for example, the library computers which don't let me install software on them.

Answer (score 2):

I came across the same problem today while trying to set up my Windows installation. There is a much better solution under Linux using ibus. Namely, you can set the output to traditional, simplified, or pinyin. This way you can take advantage of the built in recognition algorithms - they place the tone mark on the correct vowel, etc. It would be great if someone has a similar solution for Windows.

Comment: The ibus solution sounds good, but I can't find any documentation of it. I only see the Simplified and Traditional output options and no pinyin output under Ubuntu 11.10. Do you know if it's documented anywhere?

Answer (score 2):

I like the online converter at http://www.mdbg.net/chindict/webime2_pinyin.php

Just type e.g. hao3 and it directly becomes hǎo.

Answer (score 1):

I like the [pinyinput](http://pinyinput.sourceforge.net/) input method editor. Just type the letters for the syllable followed by a tone number, and it will combine them in the usual way.

Answer (score 0):

this is old, but anyway, you could use the us international keyboard, in which  you can type:
`á à ã â`

They're not the exact pinyin tone marks but resemble them very closely

Answer (score 0):

I just created https://www.pinyin-editor.com/ a couple of days ago, maybe it helps if you're still looking for a tool. Big advantage to other older web based Pinyin editors is that it's responsive, so works great on mobile

Answer (score -1):

You can type Toned-Pinyin at: [www.TypingChinese.com](http://www.typingchinese.com/main.htm)

Pinyin with tone marks can be type in SHIFT-style in 1-step.

I invented/implemented this tone pinyin input method and hope this helps.

Documentation:

http://www.typingchinese.com/TypingTonedPinyin.htm