# How to type "त" (from Hindi) in English alphabet?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, language, typing

I know there is no such syllable as "त" in English, but still is there any way we can write it with English alphabet, using any accent or anything? Like it's done for Spanish or Italian I guess?

Also **How to put a macron over vowels (ā) in Windows 7**?

I tried the Alt code from this answer-
[Is it possible to enter macron (ā) and caron (ǎ) diacritics with USA international keyboard?](https://superuser.com/questions/376020/is-it-possible-to-enter-macron-%C4%81-and-caron-%C7%8E-diacritics-with-usa-internation)

But that's clearly for Win XP. And that's an old answer. How do I do it in Win 7? Maybe there is some way now.

Comment: I'm sure that someone will answer you the correct way, a workaround can be to write it in the automatic substitution list for, i.e.,`a''`. (In Word).

Comment: Aren't you able to add a different keyboard layout and to switch to it? If you can you should only memorize/find which is its key :)

Comment: Please see [Windows Alt Key Numeric Codes](http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/accents/codealt.html). Additionally see [How to type Spanish letters and accents](http://www.spanishdict.com/answers/100808/how-to-type-spanish-letters-and-accents-#.V0AadBKwRWo).

Comment: @Hastur I don't know what you mean by "automatic substitution list". And for the macrons, there are only workarounds I could find, like the character map or as you said selecting another keyboard layout (I had to select Latvian to be able to put macron) :D

Comment: @Wishwas I definitely searched myself before asking here, and been through those links. Anyhow there is no mention of macron (ā) in those pages.

Comment: Limited to the use of the Office suite (Word,eXcel) or to the equivalent ones (LibreOffice, StarOffice...) there is a list of misspelled words that the word processor can automatically correct (see i.e. [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Automatically-correct-spelling-with-words-from-the-main-dictionary-0eac419d-e540-4b23-b438-76624dca0162#bm2)). In English it can correct ` i ` into ` I ` or `-->` in one arrow...  You can add your own,for example `a''` for `त`. If you need a system wide solution you can create a global command for that letter e.g. CTRL-ALT-SHIFT-A or whatever...

Comment: I guess this is not the right place for this question. I wanted to know how to write "त" in English. Like if I wanted to write "फ" I'd write "Fa" or for "फा" I'd write "Fā". Please also tell me how to create a global command for a letter. That indeed sounds the proper solution to me.

Comment: About the [keyboard layout](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Enable-or-change-a-keyboard-layout-language-1c2242c0-fe15-4bc3-99bc-535de6f4f258). You can use `Left Alt + Shift` to switch the input language when multiple input languages are enabled in Windows 7.  Cannot you find a suitable keyboard layout? (Maybe you have to try all the combinations included AltGr + Shift... )

Comment: Wiki about [this letter त](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E0%A4%A4) and  [about the international Transliteration of Sanskrit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Alphabet_of_Sanskrit_Transliteration), [Devanagari_transliteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devanagari_transliteration)

Comment: God damn I didn't know about this shortcut to change the keyB layout. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Typing Characters from other languages, especially languages like Hindi, is slightly roundabout.**

To type in Hindi, you have to find :

- A Hindi font (eg.[KrutiDev](http://indiatyping.com/index.php/download/95-hindi-font-krutidev)), or
- A website that allows you to type in Hindi (eg.[Gate2Home](http://gate2home.com/) or [Quillpad](http://www.quillpad.in/))

If you use a Hindi font, then every English letter on the keyboard would correspond to another Hindi letter.

On the other hand, using a website like Gate2Home that has a Hindi keyboard is a better idea because it is much more easier to manage.

**You can add a macron a vowel using the Windows Character Map.**

Steps :

1. Type ***Character Map*** in the Start Menu.
2. You can choose the font you want and after selecting the character you want,  copy that and use it wherever needed.

[image: Character Map]

Comment: Never mind about that Hindi thing. It was the wrong place to ask that question. As for the macron, I know about the character map. I was asking for an easier way like a working Alt code or some other key combination. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The "Alt codes" for the `ā` and `Ā` can be found (generally) by just putting the symbol into Google. For your character it gives us the following Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%80

The Alt codes are as follows:

> Ā = <kbd>Alt</kbd> + 0256
>   ā = <kbd>Alt</kbd> + 0257

This has to be supported by both the application and the font it uses.  I can type these characters in using Word and either the Calibri, Arial or Times New Roman fonts, but there are many fonts where these characters are missing.